# Why this return is null and not correct?

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

```
import { prisma } from "../../../database/prismaClient"

interface IDeleteHouseRequest {
    id: string
    tenantId: string
}

export class DeleteHouseUseCase {
    async execute({ id, tenantId }: IDeleteHouseRequest) {
        const findHouse = await prisma.house.findFirst({
            where: {
                id: id,
                tenantId: tenantId
            },
        })

        if (!findHouse) {
            throw new Error("It was not possible to delete this house.")
        }

        const deletedHouse = await prisma.house.delete({
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        })

        return deletedHouse
    }
}
```

*That is, the code hangs within this verification     *receiving parameters, which are coming correctly, such as ID and IDTENANT, but my !findhouse is coming as null, the data in the DB is correct, I've already checked, the item exists, and the ids are correct.
I can't pass this check.*.*

Comment: what is the value of findHouse?

Comment: It comes to me as NULL.
but I see the database the data is there.

Comment: If it's not finding the record w/ `findFirst` then either (a) the record isn't there, or (b) the props aren't what you think they are. There aren't a lot of other options for what could be going wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton actually, the error is in my tenantId, which is coming a number that is not the same as the Database, it always comes "fa080842-163b-4c16-a77e-ac0ead081afa"

and I have no idea where this id is coming from, and in the rest of the code it comes correctly :(

Comment: We also do not know where the `tenantId` is coming from because we can't see your code. You have a better chance of figuring that part out than we do at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried fetching with findMany or smth like that? Just to see what you get in result. I feel like if `findMany` returns nothing, than you have to look on your params more precisely.

Comment: @Nikita For some reason, my tenantId comes with a number that doesn't match the tenantId of the database, and I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: That's quite another story. That's not question about the tool, that's about passing parameters. Investigate what's going on there. We can't tell you about the logic there.

Comment: Is your code open source by any chance? Getting some more context would help in resolving this issue